# How do I get the id tied to the maximum date, grouped by a second id without a subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

If I have the following data scenario:

```
Id       GroupedById   Date
--       -----------   ----
1        11            1/2/17
2        11            1/4/17
3        11            1/3/17
4        12            4/1/17
5        12            1/1/17
6        12            2/1/17
```

What I want in my result set is:

```
Id       GroupedById   Date
--       -----------   ----
2        11            1/4/17
4        12            4/1/17
```

I was trying a combination of `Group By` and `Having`, I also tried `Over (Partition By)`, but none seemed to do the trick. However, when I include the `Id` field, I get more than just the `GroupedById` and max date.

`SELECT GroupById, MAX(Date) FROM MyTable Group By GroupById` gets me the `GroupById` and maximum date, but I'm not sure how to get the corresponding `Id` with that combination.

Comment: Why "without a subquery"?  How about a CTE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number` with `TOP`.

```
select top 1 with ties *
from tbl
order by row_number() over(partition by groupedID order by date desc)
```

Comment: This is only going to give me the top row a result set. If you look at what I was asking for, I wanted the highest date for each `GroupById` and then the `Id` that went with the combination of `GroupedById` and `Date`

Comment: use `top 1 with ties`.